# Computer crash breaks sencha cmd?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

My computer crashed while I was building my sencha touch project with sencha cmd and now I can't build it anymore without error. I was hoping someone might have some insight - I re-installed sencha cmd thinking it might have been a corrupt file there but no luck. Here is the output from the build with the debug flag turned on:

> sencha -d app build native > dbg.txt

```
Sencha Cmd v4.0.0.203
[DBG] Loading configuration from E:\SkyDrive\Projects\PersonalTraining\Development\offlinemobile
[DBG] Scanning for extensions in C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions
[DBG] Loaded extension: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\cmd-cordova-packager
[DBG] Loaded extension: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\cmd-phonegap-packager
[DBG] Loaded extension: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-compass
[DBG] Loaded extension: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io
[DBG] Framework dependency detected
[DBG] Loading framework touch from E:\SkyDrive\Projects\PersonalTraining\Development\offlinemobile\touch
[DBG] Detecting framework plugin
[DBG] Resolving framework config overrides for 'touch'
[DBG] Detected framework version 2.3.0
[DBG] Detected framework override at 'C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\plugins\touch\2.3'
[DBG] using framework plugin located at 'C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\plugins\touch\2.3'
[DBG] Loaded framework from E:\SkyDrive\Projects\PersonalTraining\Development\offlinemobile\touch
[DBG] Loading CommandProviders
[DBG] Scanning extensions directory C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\cmd-cordova-packager for extensions
[DBG] Scanning extensions directory C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\cmd-phonegap-packager for extensions
[DBG] Scanning extensions directory C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-compass for extensions
[DBG] Located C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-compass\sencha-compass.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-compass\sencha-compass.jar
[DBG] get value lib/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar lib/ant-1.8.4.jar lib/ant-launcher-1.8.4.jar for manifest class path
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-compass\lib\slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-compass\lib\ant-1.8.4.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-compass\lib\ant-launcher-1.8.4.jar
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-compass' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-compass/sencha-compass.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-compass' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-compass/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-compass' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-compass/lib/ant-1.8.4.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-compass' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-compass/lib/ant-launcher-1.8.4.jar!/
[DBG] Scanning extensions directory C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io for extensions
[DBG] Located C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io\sencha-io.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io\sencha-io.jar
[DBG] get value lib/httpclient-4.2.1.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar lib/httpclient-cache-4.2.1.jar lib/httpcore-4.2.1.jar lib/httpmime-4.2.1.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar lib/gson-2.2.1.jar for manifest class path
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io\lib\httpclient-4.2.1.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io\lib\commons-codec-1.6.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io\lib\httpclient-cache-4.2.1.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io\lib\httpcore-4.2.1.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io\lib\httpmime-4.2.1.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io\lib\slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io\lib\gson-2.2.1.jar
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-io/sencha-io.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-io/lib/httpclient-4.2.1.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-io/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-io/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-io/lib/httpclient-cache-4.2.1.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-io/lib/httpcore-4.2.1.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-io/lib/httpmime-4.2.1.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-io/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/Stephen/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/extensions/sencha-io/lib/gson-2.2.1.jar!/
[DBG] Scanning for plugins in folder: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\cmd-cordova-packager
[DBG] Loading plugin: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\cmd-cordova-packager\cmd-cordova-packager.plugin.xml
[DBG] Resolving packages for : App
[DBG] scanning directory E:\SkyDrive\Projects\PersonalTraining\Development\offlinemobile/touch for packages
[DBG] scanning directory E:\SkyDrive\Projects\PersonalTraining\Development\offlinemobile/packages for packages
[DBG] Resolving packages for : App
[DBG] Scanning for plugins in folder: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\cmd-phonegap-packager
[DBG] Loading plugin: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\cmd-phonegap-packager\cmd-phonegap-packager.plugin.xml
[DBG] Scanning for plugins in folder: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-compass
[DBG] Scanning for plugins in folder: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io
[DBG] Scanning for plugins in folder: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\cmd-cordova-packager
[DBG] Loading plugin: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\cmd-cordova-packager\cmd-cordova-packager.plugin.xml
[DBG] Scanning for plugins in folder: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\cmd-phonegap-packager
[DBG] Loading plugin: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\cmd-phonegap-packager\cmd-phonegap-packager.plugin.xml
[DBG] Scanning for plugins in folder: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-compass
[DBG] Scanning for plugins in folder: C:\Users\Stephen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment$Failure.check(BuildEnvironment.java:754)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.checkState(BuildEnvironment.java:329)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.mustGetAppEnvironment(BuildEnvironment.java:558)
     at com.sencha.command.BaseSenchaCommand.mustGetAppEnvironment(BaseSenchaCommand.java:32)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:116)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:174)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:81)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:149)
   Caused by: null
     at com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException.wrap(BasicException.java:51)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment$Failure.<init>(BuildEnvironment.java:749)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment$3.call(BuildEnvironment.java:733)
     at com.sencha.util.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:61)
     at com.sencha.util.Configuration.each(Configuration.java:180)
     at com.sencha.util.Configuration.each(Configuration.java:223)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.apply(AntScript.java:80)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:188)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.load(PluginManager.java:138)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.scan(PluginManager.java:167)
     at com.sencha.command.ant.AntCommandScanner.getCommandTargets(AntCommandScanner.java:37)
     at com.sencha.command.ant.AntExtensionScanner.getExtensionTargets(AntExtensionScanner.java:31)
     at com.sencha.command.ant.AntExtensionScanner.getExtensionTargets(AntExtensionScanner.java:20)
     at com.sencha.command.ant.AntExtensionScanner.getExtensionCommands(AntExtensionScanner.java:35)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.extendCommands(Sencha.java:443)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.extendCommands(Commands.java:103)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.commands(Commands.java:44)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.findCommand(Commands.java:83)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:65)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:81)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:149)
   Caused by: null
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.HttpRepository.fixUrl(HttpRepository.java:151)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.HttpRepository.<init>(HttpRepository.java:36)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository$Type$1.create(RemoteRepository.java:33)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository.<init>(RemoteRepository.java:74)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository.<init>(RemoteRepository.java:102)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository.<init>(RemoteRepository.java:106)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RepositoryRemoteManagerImpl$1.accept(RepositoryRemoteManagerImpl.java:28)
     at java.io.File.listFiles(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RepositoryRemoteManagerImpl.<init>(RepositoryRemoteManagerImpl.java:26)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.LocalRepository.loadConfig(LocalRepository.java:916)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.LocalRepository.<init>(LocalRepository.java:97)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.getLocalRepository(WorkspaceRepository.java:262)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.getCatalog(WorkspaceRepository.java:241)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.resolvePackageModels(WorkspaceRepository.java:117)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.resolvePackageEnvironments(WorkspaceRepository.java:97)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.getRequiredPackageEnvironments(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:187)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.getRequiredPackagesNoThemes(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:248)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.getRequiredPackageNamesNoThemes(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:239)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppEnvironment$3.call(AppEnvironment.java:80)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppEnvironment$3.call(AppEnvironment.java:78)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment$3.call(BuildEnvironment.java:731)
     at com.sencha.util.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:61)
     at com.sencha.util.Configuration.each(Configuration.java:180)
     at com.sencha.util.Configuration.each(Configuration.java:223)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.apply(AntScript.java:80)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:188)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.load(PluginManager.java:138)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.scan(PluginManager.java:167)
     at com.sencha.command.ant.AntCommandScanner.getCommandTargets(AntCommandScanner.java:37)
     at com.sencha.command.ant.AntExtensionScanner.getExtensionTargets(AntExtensionScanner.java:31)
     at com.sencha.command.ant.AntExtensionScanner.getExtensionTargets(AntExtensionScanner.java:20)
     at com.sencha.command.ant.AntExtensionScanner.getExtensionCommands(AntExtensionScanner.java:35)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.extendCommands(Sencha.java:443)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.extendCommands(Commands.java:103)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.commands(Commands.java:44)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.findCommand(Commands.java:83)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:65)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:81)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:149)




    Process finished with exit code 321 at 14:47:48.
    Execution time: 2,311 ms.
```

I then tried to build a new project to just copy all my files into and that also failed. Very frustrating and I'm at a loss for how to move forward at this point, any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know what other information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMD can be a bit difficult to work with sometimes when it comes to uncommon errors/bugs, you end up getting caught up trying to track down the root through these huge error stacks. From extensive experience we can almost bet the issue is related to other packages/programs that CMD uses (which is a fair amount). I'm not sure what kind of system you are running, or what exactly you mean by "computer crashed" - but here are a few things I recommend:

- Update all packages and CMD, try killing non-vital services temporarily, etc.
- Try compiling all different build types (testing, production, etc) and see if it always errors at the same spot.
- Go into the .sencha/app folder, and look for .properties files. These contain your default and environment build rules. Start slowly commenting/disabling entries to see if you can track down a specific step that is causing the error.

When you tried copying over your files, what exactly did you build fresh vs copy over? Just try generating (via CMD commands) an empty starter app and building - see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  By computer crashed, I mean there was a memory error and it blue screened (windows).  I tried just upgrading cmd and still couldn't do anything (build my existing app or generate a new one).  I ended up uninstalling all the previous versions of command and re-installing the version I had been using.   I can at least generate a new app and have copied over my code and got things building again now.

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same problem today. Also after a computer crash.

**What worked for me**

- Uninstall Sencha cmd
- Remove the bin folder for Sencha Cmd (%userprofile\bin on windows by default)
- Install Sencha Cmd

**What didn't work**

Removing my entire project folder (with the .sencha folder) and checking it out again from repository didn't help so it's not the files in the project. The project built fine on other machines.

Reinstalling Sencha Cmd didn't help. Building production instead of testing gives the same error.